# How to tell latex to write as the text in texmaker?

Tags: formatting, packages, verbatim

I intend to attach my C code in my report. However, the code has a lot of special characters that create an error in compilation {, # and so on. 
Any package to circumvent this issue.

For example:

```
\# include'<'stdio.h\> 

\# include ...
int main()

{
for i = 1:10:100

}
```

so on should have the curly bracket and hash as it is in the output.

Comment: Packages `listings`, `minted`, `tcolorbox` (with `minted` or `listings` as options etc.)

Comment: Your `C` code is ...strange ;-)

Comment: One word that has not yet been mentioned is `verbatim`.   This is the LaTeX word that describes your problem. There are many facilities in LaTeX for handling input `verbatim`, and a search of this site on that word should be very illuminating to your education on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `listings` way, without no further configuration, and a `tcolorbox` listings box, which is configurable for the `listing options` and other other options for the pure display

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,listing options={numbers=left,language={C++}}, left=15pt,enhanced, colback=white!40!yellow,drop shadow, sharp corners}
  #include <iostream>
  // Hello World - Example
  int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
  }
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Solved]Thank you for such a prompt response.

Comment: @AdityaBudaraju [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark (✓). This will indicate the question has been answered, and you won't need to add [Solved], like in a forum.

Comment: The result shown here looks strange. Usage of a proportional font with monospaced positions of letters and math characters like < is absurd.

Comment: @wipet: This is the default setup of `listings`, if no other settings are used. The O.P. may change to his own needs ;-)